# Amsbook + Paracol pagebreak broken with mdframed

Tags: listings, amsbook, paracol

I am trying to typeset some code and some commentary side-by-side using `paracol` and `listings` with the `amsbook` document class. It mostly works but I encounter a bug, when there is a pagebreak the paragraph immediately *following* the pagebreak is "flush bottom". For example:

[image]

Before the page break, the left column starts vertically aligned with the right column, but after the page break this is no longer true.

If I remove the `mdframed` background from the `listings` environment, things work as expected:

[image]

(It's a little harder to discern without the vertical lines separating the "chunks" in the right column, but it's true.)

**This only is a problem with the `amsbook` document class**, at least in my experiments with comparing the output to `book`, `article`, and `amsart`. I honestly do not understand what `amsbook` is doing differently which breaks things.

It does not seem to be related to syntax highlighting or color usage, or font encoding.

The minimal working example to reproduce this, although length (sorry):

```latex
\documentclass[leqno,oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage[inner=6pc,outer=6pc,bottom=6pc,top=5pc,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfsetup{skipabove=\medskipamount,
  outermargin=0pt,
  innermargin=0pt,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  rightmargin=0pt,
  innerleftmargin=0.25em,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  rightline=false,
  leftline=false,
  frametitlerule=false,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt,
  splittopskip=\topsep
}
\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  language=Mizar,
}
\lstnewenvironment{mizar}%
                  {\lstset{language=Mizar,
                      basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
                      upquote=true}\mdframed[usetwoside=false]}%
                  {\endmdframed}

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foundations}
\section{Tarski Grothendieck Set Theory}

\begin{paracol}{2}
For simplicity we adopt the following convention: $x$, $y$,
$z$, $u$ will denote objects of any type; $N$, $M$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$
will denote objects of the type set.
  
Next we will state two axioms:
\begin{equation}
x \mbox{ is } \textrm{set},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(\mbox{ for } x\mbox{ holds } x\in X\mbox{ iff } x\in Y)\mbox{ implies } X=Y.
\end{equation}

\switchcolumn

\begin{mizar}
 reserve x,y,z,u for object;
 reserve N,M,X,Y,Z for set;

:: Everything is a set
theorem :: TARSKI:1
  for x being object holds x is set;

:: Extensionality
theorem :: TARSKI:2 
  (for x being object
   holds x in X iff x in Y)
  implies X = Y;
\end{mizar}

\switchcolumn*

We now introduce two functors. Let us consider $y$. The functor
\[ \{\,y\,\} \]
with values of the type set, is defined by
\[ x\in\mbox{ it } \mbox{ iff } x=y.\]
Let us consider $z$. The functor
\[ \{\,y,z\,\} \]
with values of the type set, is defined by
\[ x\in\mbox{ it } \mbox{ iff } x=y \mbox{ or } x=z.\]
The following axioms hold:
\begin{equation}
X=\{y\} \mbox{ iff }\ \mbox{ for } x \mbox{ holds } x\in X \mbox{ iff } x=y,
\end{equation}
\begin{multline}
X=\{y,z\} \mbox{ iff }\ \mbox{ for } x\mbox{ holds } x\in X\mbox{ iff }\\
%\textbf{iff}~
x=y\mbox{ or } x=z.
\end{multline}

\switchcolumn

\begin{mizar}
definition
  let y be object;
  func { y } -> set means
:: TARSKI:def 1
    for x being object
    holds x in it iff x = y;

  let z be object;
  func { y, z } -> set means
:: TARSKI:def 2
    x in it iff x = y or x = z;
  commutativity;
end;
\end{mizar}

\switchcolumn*


Let us consider $X$, $Y$. The predicate
\[ X\subset Y\quad\mbox{is defined by}\quad x\in
X\mbox{ implies } x\in Y.\]
\switchcolumn
\begin{mizar}
definition 
  let X,Y;
  pred X c= Y
  means :: TARSKI:def 3
  for x being object 
  holds x in X implies x in Y;
  reflexivity;
end;
\end{mizar}

\switchcolumn*
Let us consider $X$. The functor
\[\bigcup X,\]
with values of the type set, is defined by
\[x\in\mbox{ it }\ \mbox{ iff }\ \mbox{ ex } Y\mbox{ st } x\in Y\mathrel{\&} Y\in X.\] 
Then we get
\begin{multline}
X=\bigcup Y\mbox{ iff }\ \mbox{ for } x\mbox{ holds } x\in
X\mbox{ iff }\\
\mbox{ ex } Z\mbox{ st } x\in Z\mathrel{\&} Z\in Y,
\end{multline}
\begin{equation}
X=\mbox{ bool } Y\mbox{ iff }\ \mbox{ for } Z\mbox{ holds } 
Z\in X \mbox{ iff } Z\subset Y.
\end{equation}

\switchcolumn

\begin{mizar}
definition 
  let X;
  func union X -> set means
:: TARSKI:def 4
    x in it iff ex Y st x in Y & Y in X;
end;
\end{mizar}

\switchcolumn*


The regularity axiom claims that
\begin{multline}
x\in X\mbox{ implies }\ \mbox{ ex } Y\mbox{ st } Y\in X\mathrel{\&}\\
\neg\ \mbox{ ex } x\mbox{ st } x\in X\mathrel{\&} x\in Y.
\end{multline}

\switchcolumn

\begin{mizar}
:: Regularity
theorem :: TARSKI:3
  x in X implies
   ex Y st Y in X &
     not ex x st x in X & x in Y;
\end{mizar}

\begin{mizar}
definition let x, X be set;
  redefine pred x in X;
  asymmetry;
end;
\end{mizar}

\switchcolumn*


The scheme \textit{Fraenkel} deals with a constant $\mathcal{A}$ that
has the type set and a binary predicate $\mathcal{P}$ and states that
the following holds:
\begin{multline*}
  \mbox{ ex } X\mbox{ st }\ \mbox{ for } x\mbox{ holds } \\
  x\in X\mbox{ iff }
\mbox{ ex } y\mbox{ st } y\in\mathcal{A}\mathrel{\&}\mathcal{P}[y,x]
\end{multline*}
provided the parameters satisfy the following extra condition:
\begin{itemize}
\item $\mbox{ for }$ $x$, $y$, $z$ $\mbox{ st }$ 
  $\mathcal{P}[x,y]\mathrel{\&}\mathcal{P}[x,z]$ $\mbox{ holds }$  $y=z$.
\end{itemize}

\switchcolumn

\begin{mizar}
scheme :: TARSKI:sch 1
 Replacement{ A() -> set,
              P[object,object] }:
 ex X
 st for x being object 
    holds x in X iff
          ex y being object 
          st y in A() & P[y,x]
provided
 for x,y,z being object 
 st P[x,y] & P[x,z]
 holds y = z;
\end{mizar}

\switchcolumn*


Let us consider $x$, $y$. The functor
\[\langle x,y\rangle,\]
is defined by
\[\mbox{ it } = \{\,\{x,y\,\},\{\,x\,\}\,\}.\]
According to the definition
\begin{equation}
\langle x,y\rangle = \{\,\{x,y\,\},\{\,x\,\}\,\}.
\end{equation}

\switchcolumn
\begin{mizar}
definition
  let x,y be object;
  func [x,y] -> object equals
:: TARSKI:def 5
    { { x,y }, { x } };
end;
\end{mizar}


\switchcolumn*

Let us consider $X$, $Y$. The predicate
\[X\approx Y\]
is defined by
\begin{multline*}
\mbox{ ex } Z\mbox{ st }\!\! (\mbox{ for } x\mbox{ st } x\in X\mbox{ ex } 
y\mbox{ st } y\in Y\mathrel{\&}\langle x,y\rangle\in Z)\mathrel{\&}\\
(\mbox{ for } x\mbox{ st } x\in X\mbox{ ex } 
y\mbox{ st } y\in Y\mathrel{\&}\langle x,y\rangle\in Z)\mathrel{\&}\\
\mbox{ for } x,y,z,u\mbox{ st } \langle x,y\rangle\in Z\mathrel{\&}\langle z,u\rangle\in Z\\
\mbox{ holds } x=z\mbox{ iff } y=u.
\end{multline*}

\switchcolumn

\begin{mizar}
definition let X,Y;
  pred X,Y are_equipotent means
:: TARSKI:def 6
  ex Z st
  (for x st x in X
   ex y st y in Y & [x,y] in Z) &
  (for y st y in Y
   ex x st x in X & [x,y] in Z) &
  for x,y,z,u st [x,y] in Z & [z,u] in Z
  holds x = z iff y = u;
end;
\end{mizar}

\switchcolumn*
The Tarski's axiom A claims that
\begin{multline}
\mbox{ ex }  M \mbox{ st } N\in M\mathrel{\&}\\
(\mbox{ for } X,Y \mbox{ holds }  X\in M\mathrel{\&}
Y\subset X \mbox{ implies } Y\in M)\mathrel{\&}\\
(\mbox{ for } X \mbox{ holds }  X\in M
 \mbox{ implies } \mbox{ bool } X\in M)\mathrel{\&}\\
(\mbox{ for } X \mbox{ holds }  X\subset M \mbox{ implies } 
X\approx M \mbox{ or } X\in M).
\end{multline}

\switchcolumn\nopagebreak

\begin{mizar}
theorem :: TARSKI_A:1
 ex M st N in M &
   (for X,Y holds X in M & Y c= X
    implies Y in M) &
   (for X st X in M
    ex Z st Z in M &
            for Y st Y c= X
            holds Y in Z) &
   (for X holds X c= M 
    implies X,M are_equipotent
            or X in M);
\end{mizar}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Using PDFlatex (version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 from TeX live 2022) this produces a 3-page PDF which has the misaligned left column immediately after both page breaks.

If I add, e.g., `\ensurevspace{5cm}` to each `\switchcolumn*`, then the situation remains unchanged as far as this bizarre bug is concerned.

(And my actual TeX code looks much cleaner than this, with semantic macros, etc., but this is the smallest self-contained example I could create.)

Comment: Both mdframed and paracol mess with \output, so one would expect them to be incompatible.  I don't recall anything special about amsart.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I expected the same thing, but as I noted this bug is not observable in the vanilla `book` document class or the `article` class...which made me suspect it was AMS class witchcraft. This is why I tried testing it with `amsart`, because they use exactly the same output algorithm modulo a few minor details (which shouldn't produce this problem).

Comment: I think `\flushbottom` is a backwards way of thinking about' this.  Observe the wide gap at the top of the continuation page when `mdframed` is removed -- it's the same in both columns.  But when `mdframed` is present, that column is shoved up to the top.  (I'm guessing that the wider gap is what is desired.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Excellent eye! I missed that detail and, when I tried using just the vanilla `book` class, that "gap" at the top of the page was fixed. It seems that `amsbook` is using some really quirky (with a capital "K") algorithm for its output function.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your insight proved invaluable! It turns out that `amsbook` implemented its `\chapter` macro to globally adjust the `topskip`, making it 7.5pc forever (when they just wanted to add 7.5 pc of vertical whitespace before the "Chapter [number]" formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Barbara Beeton had a profound insight, which made me examine the code more closely for `amsbook`. I discovered there is this macro which is invoked whenever a chapter starts, and it changes the `topskip` to be `7.5pc` globally...which is, well, not the intended goal of that particular line of code. The fix is to add the following lines:

```tex
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\vspace*{7.5pc}\relax%
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bfseries\centering
    \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
      \leavevmode \hskip-\leftskip
      \rlap{\vbox to\z@{\vss
          \centerline{\normalsize\mdseries
              \uppercase\@xp{\chaptername}\enspace\thechapter}
          \vskip 3pc}}\hskip\leftskip\fi
     #1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\vspace*{7.5pc}\relax
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bfseries\centering
  #1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }
\makeatother
```

This only changes the first line, changing `\global\topskip7.5pc` to `\vspaces*{7.5pc}`. Apparently that was the goal, according to the documentation, and no one really bothered to check if the code *actually did that.*

Comment: Alex, I used to help maintain the AMS classes, and I never saw this happen.  I don't think it did, but I don't ever remember seeing any use of `paracol`, and `mdframed` only a few times.  I've taken a quick look at the code, and it seems that `\topskip` isn't properly reset to `\normaltopsep` as it should be.  I'll refer this problem to the current AMS technical support team for a proper fix.  (I retired in 2019, so am no longer officially involved.)

Comment: Alex, message sent.  I suggested that the technical person get in touch with you to ask for some extra help -- there is extra pfutzing around with the title block for the 2-column index, which is a bit of a beast.  Although the package is dated 2020, I sincerely doubt that the code for the chapter heading has been looked at for more than fifteen years.  (Michael Downes, the author, died in 2003, and I'm sure I never touched it.  It's a mystery to me why that specific `\topskip` might need to be defined as global.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you so much! I'd be happy to help however I can. And thanks again for your keen eye, I was so hyperfocused on the wrong track I would missed this entirely.